# Has anyone written an STS wrapper to Facebook Connect and Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, adfs2.0

Has anyone written a secure token service that wraps the Facebook connect API that they are willing to share?

We are considering this as an alternative to using Azure ACS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sign into SharePoint 2010 with Facebook using a custom STS](http://blogs.pointbridge.com/Blogs/nielsen_travis/Pages/Post.aspx?_ID=40) shows how to integrate the Facebook part with a custom STS. You can pretty much ignore the SP 2010 part (unless that's what you are using?).

Also, have a look at [Startersts](http://startersts.codeplex.com/). Not specifically about Facebook but it does have a sample on how to build a bridge between OpenId and WS-Federation.